# My auto resize cell in collectionview resized twice

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell, autoresize

I want to auto resize my cell of my collectionview accordingly with the content.When i click on a cell it looks like that my cell is resizing twice.

What i have done:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0fCj.jpg

My code:

MainViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        }
}
```

Also i have tried this with no luck:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout,
            let collectionView = collectionView {
            let width = (collectionView.frame.width - 70) / 1.9
            let height = (collectionView.frame.height - 100) / 10
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        }
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = view.frame.size.width - 40
        let height = (view.frame.size.height - 100) / 6
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)


        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let width = (view.frame.size.width - 70) / 1.9
            let height = (view.frame.size.height - 100) / 10
            let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            return layout.itemSize
        }

        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let width = (view.frame.size.width - 70) / 1.9
            let height = (view.frame.size.height - 100) / 10
            let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            return layout.itemSize
        }

        return layout.itemSize
    }
```

MyBusinessCell.swift:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
        var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame
        return layoutAttributes
    }
```

PS: I think that the resize works but why is doing that twice?

Comment: Well for one thing isn't it a bit over the top to say `setNeedsLayout(); layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at your resizing code, and then look in the stack trace where the call originates from.

Comment: And without them i have the same results @matt